# Salesforce/php - downloaded image attachments are corrupted - Any Ideas?

Tags: php, web-services, salesforce

Here is my code for downloading attachment from Salesforce.com using php toolkit and enterprise wsdl:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.jpg"');        
    $mySforceConnection = getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT Id, Name, Body from Attachment Where Id ='" .$id ."'";
    $queryResult = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

    $records = $queryResult->records;
    print_r(base64_decode($records[0]->fields->Body));
```

When I do this the file gets downloaded correctly with correct number of bytes but when I open the image, the windows image viewer says its corrupt. Any idea why this is happening?

The same code works fine for PDFs and text files.

Comment: Have you tried in anything other than the windows image viewer? Maybe the extension doesn't match the file type? Are you sure it's jpg?

Comment: Won't print_r mess up? I mean `echo` is straightforward, `print_r` will do the indentation etc, make code look really nice if wrapped in `<pre>` tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to just echo the output, as @eyescream mentioned.  When you use the `print_r` function, additional tab and newline characters are placed into the output to make it more readable.  A plain `echo` would output properly.

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.jpg"');

$mySforceConnection = getConnection();

$query = "SELECT Id, Name, Body from Attachment Where Id ='" .$id ."'";
$queryResult = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

$records = $queryResult->records;
echo base64_decode($records[0]->fields->Body);
```